# Express.js - End route chain from middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I have an Express.js 4 app, with an error logging middleware of the following form:

```
...
const logErrors = (err, req, res, next) => {
  logger.error(err);
  res.status(400).json({ error: err.message });
}
app.use(logErrors);
```

I was previously under the (incorrect) assumption, that by not calling `next()` the request would simply not continue onto my route handler. This is not the case as when an error occurs, it gets logged and sent as a response to the user but the request continues to `/myroutehandler` where it causes problems.

How do I stop the route/middleware chain after I've logged and responded to the error in my middleware? or what is the correct way to go about this?

Bonus question: Since I am not calling `next()` shouldn't the request hang? how/why is express handling this?

EDIT:

More of my code, to figure out why request jumps from the middleware to the route

```
app.use(morgan('combined', { stream: logger.inputStream }));
app.use(authMiddleware);
app.use(xmlParser({
  normalize: false,
  normalizeTags: false,
  trim: true,
  mergeAttrs: true,
  explicitArray: false
}));
app.use(logErrors);

app.post('/HotLeadsFeed', async (req, res) => {
  if (!req.body || !req.body.pi || !req.body.pi.pa) {
    //error logging
  }
  try {
    //logic
  } catch (err) {
    //error handling
  }
});
```

Comment: Where is your error middleware placed in the chain? It should be the last. To answer the bonus question, if you're ending the response with `res.json()` or `res.send()` you don't need to call `next`.

Comment: It is in fact the last middleware before the first route. Oh so when I can `res.json()` it automatically calls `next()` for me?

Comment: a) It should be after all `app.use` and routes defined. It should be absolute last (see http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html). b) No - the response is just ended at that point i.e. the middleware chain terminates.

Comment: Thank you! moving it to absolute last fixed the issue. But now im wondering why does the request jump from my middeware to my `/route` when i DONT call `next()`?

Comment: That shouldn't happen. I'll have to see more of your code to analyze that, including how you've defined your routes etc.

Comment: Have added my code above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160199/discussion-between-vasan-and-user3690467).